# Proof of the Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

How is the euclidean algorithm infallible? An intuitive approach or sketch of the proof would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried looking through the Wikipedia page or Brilliant? As far as I know, you have not shown any research effort.

Comment: I have checked Wikipedia but i wasn't able to completely grasp it.. so i will check Brilliant. Thank you!!

Comment: Update: I checked Brilliant and it says nothing about the algorithm's infallibity.. Seemingly, only Wikipedia provides the comprehensive proof for the algorithm, so I will stick with it. Thank you again :) @TobyMak

Comment: Can you find a counterexample ? How would you proceed to find a flaw ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I couldn't find neither a counterexample nor a flaw. On the other hand, i cannot acquiesce to its validity as well _without_ proving it

Comment: Trying to find a flaw is a reasoning of the same nature as trying to find a proof. It can be an alternative way to understand the algorithm. In the case at hand, you should wonder "why the Hell do they take the remainder ?".

Comment: Exactly what i thought! I couldn't understand what the secret behind that remainder was, and it was very conflicting. Thank you for your time and insight!

Comment: @OmarS: allow me a last comment. If you design an algorithm on the idea of the $\gcd$ invariant, you can be inspired by the property "$b$ and $a-qb<a$ have the same $\gcd$ as $a,b$". A simple option is to take $q=1$, leading to a "subtractive" Euclidean algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations). Another option is to try and find the $q$ that leads to the *strongest* reduction of $a$, and that is the quotient of the division and finally the rule is $a\leftarrow a\bmod b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof shows that

- every step of the algorithm preserves the $\gcd$ of the two numbers.
- every step but the last reduces the numbers.

The proof concludes by observing that as the numbers cannot be reduced anymore, you have found the $\gcd$, and this occurs after a finite number of steps.

---

Technically:

- $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,a\bmod b)$ because $a\bmod b$ and $a$ differ by a multiple of $b$.
- $b<a\implies a\bmod b<a$.

If $a=b$, then $\gcd(a,b)=a$.

---

**Addendum:**

It can be shown that the largest number of steps occurs when the input numbers are two successive Fibonacci numbers, so that the number of steps is bounded by $\log_\phi a$.

Comment: On the first bullet you mentioned, you mean that:
**gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,r)** (if we assume a=bq+r)
And then this follows until we reach r_i=0. Right?

Comment: @OmarS: exactly. This is called an *invariant*: during the execution of the algorithm, the $\gcd$ of $a,b$ never changes, even if $a,b$ themselves change.

Comment: That's it!! I have never come across this. Thank you so much!!